# Mule 4 - Parse DateTime as DD/MM/YYYY 24HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: date, datetime, mule, dataweave, mule4

I am stuck with a requirement where I need to parse incoming payload String `6-12-2019 2:13:30` to DateTime format `DD/MM/YYYY 24HH:MM:SS`

I tried few approaches but nothing seems to work here.

`"6-12-2019 2:13:30" as DateTime {format : "d-M-yyyy h:m:ss"}` 
this results in error stating...

`"Cannot coerce String (6-12-2019 2:13:30) to DateTime, caused by: Text '6-12-2019 2:13:30' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporaAccessor: {SecondOfMinute=30, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=2, MinuteOfHour=13, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO resolved to 2019-12-06 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Studio’s preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input doesn't match the type DateTime. It is missing a timezone, and the 'h' format character implicates it is an AM/PM date, but it is missing it. A LocalDateTime doesn't need a timezone. You can either change the input and format or change the type.

Please find below some valid examples:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    localDateTime: "6-12-2019 2:13:30 pm" as LocalDateTime {format : "d-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a"},
    localDateTime24h: "6-12-2019 14:13:30" as LocalDateTime {format : "d-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss"},
    dateTime: "6-12-2019 2:13:30 +0500" as DateTime {format : "d-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss Z"}
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "localDateTime": "6-12-2019 2:13:30 PM",
  "localDateTime24h": "6-12-2019 14:13:30",
  "dateTime": "6-12-2019 2:13:30 +0500"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast the incoming date to your specific format. And then reformat as need. In below sample, we converted the date to `MM/dd/yyyy` format and the reformatted it to the required format i.e. `y-MM-dd`.
(date1 as Date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"}) as String {format: "y-MM-dd"}